# Is it possible to parallelize an Iterator that uses Yield?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parallel.foreach, parallel-extensions

Consider this code, which extends the Array .NET type :

```
Public Module ArrayExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Iterator Function ToEnumerable(Of T)(target As Array) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        For Each item In target
            Yield DirectCast(item, T)
        Next
    End Function
End Module
```

I use it to get a structure which the Min() and Max() extension methods will take. The arrays often run to several million elements in three dimensions, e.g. an array `T(,,)` is common.

EDIT: Specifically, this function comes into play with a line of code that looks like this:

```
    Return loadedData(rType).dataArray.ToEnumerable(Of Single).Min
```

where `dataarray` is (in this case) a value item in the `ConcurrentDictionary` `loadedData` and is of type `Single(,,)`

Without the `ToEnumerable` as currently written, there is no IEnumerable interface for the `Max()` extension function to hook to.

What would it take to "parallelize" this function? No form of `Parallel.For` that I've tried seems to work, because the `loadedData` array is not recognized as an `IEnumerable` type. (Is this because a Single(,,) is processed as a value type, perhaps?)

(No answer has to use VB. C# is also fine!)

Comment: In my opinion you don't need this method at all. You can use [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It seems you re-invented `Cast` method

Comment: I might have, but that's not the question. The question is: How to parallelize?

Comment: So you want to parallelize this without using Paralell API is it?

Comment: @RobPerkins, how about `ParallelEnumerable.Cast<TResult>` ?

Comment: No... I haven't been able to get it to work with Parallel API. It's not clear that it won't, only that I haven't succeeded. If it can work with that and be a clear piece of code, that's OK.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, the input is type `System.Array` defined as something like `float[,,]`, which is not a `ParallelQuery` type.

Comment: @RobPerkins, no, but you can make it parallel with `AsParallel()`... Your code would become `target.AsParallel().Cast<T>()`

Comment: No, that doesn't work. See edits.

Comment: Show some code. If it isn't working include the error (if any) and the line it happens on, and if there is no error show the exppected and actual results. 'It doesn't work' isn't a lot to go on.

Comment: The posted code and description is not enough to understand the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use `AsParallel()` on that (e.g. `dataArray.ToEnumerable().AsParallel().Min()`). But the `IEnumerable` interface is inherently serial, you can parallelize processing its elements, but not iterating it. This means that for very simpler operations like `Min()`, such parallelization doesn't make much sense.

What could make sense here would be to parallelize the iteration too. This is possible, because you can access particular items of the array using the indexer.

I tried to do this using a [custom partitioner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411), but the results were worse than the serial version. The problem is that the overhead of each iteration has to be as small as possible and that's hard to do directly using partitioners.

Instead, what you could do is to partition only the first dimension of your array (assuming you can be sure it's at least as big as your number of CPUs) and then use a version of `ToEnumerable()` that returns only part of the first dimension. Something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T[,,] array, int from, int to)
{
    for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(2); k++)
            {
                yield return array[i, j, k];
            }
        }
    }
}

Partitioner.Create(0, data.GetLength(0))
           .AsParallel()
           .Select(range => data.ToEnumerable(range.Item1, range.Item2).Min())
           .Min()
```

This is about twice as fast as the serial version on my computer. But this still has the overhead of enumerator, which is quite significant in this case: this version is about twice as fast as the above parallel code:

```
var length0 = data.GetLength(0);
var length1 = data.GetLength(1);
var length2 = data.GetLength(2);

float min = float.MaxValue;

for (int i = 0; i < length0; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length1; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < length2; k++)
        {
            float value = data[i, j, k];
            if (value < min)
                min = value;
        }
    }
}

return min;
```

And now we can parallelize this code, which results in about four times speedup (as before, we partition the first dimension and then continue serially):

```
var results = new ConcurrentQueue<float>();
var length1 = data.GetLength(1);
var length2 = data.GetLength(2);

Parallel.ForEach(
    Partitioner.Create(0, data.GetLength(0)), range =>
    {
        float min = float.MaxValue;

        for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < length1; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < length2; k++)
                {
                    float value = data[i, j, k];
                    if (value < min)
                        min = value;
                }
            }
        }

        results.Enqueue(min);
    });

return results.Min();
```

But wait! There's more. Multidimensional arrays are quite slow in .Net, so from a performance standpoint, it can make sense to use a jagged array (`float[][][]` instead of `float[,,]`), even if a multidimensional array fits better. Using this, we can get about 50 % more speedup:

```
dataJagged.AsParallel().Min(
    level1 =>
    {
        float min = float.MaxValue;

        foreach (var level2 in level1)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < level2.Length; k++)
            {
                float value = level2[k];
                if (value < min)
                    min = value;
            }
        }

        return min;
    });
```

To sum up, there is a table of timings on my computer using the various approaches:

- 3D array, `ToEnumerable`, serial: 18.6 s
- 3D array, `ToEnumerable`, PLINQ: 7.4 s
- 3D array, manual loops, serial: 4.0 s
- 3D array, manual loops, `Parallel.ForEach`: 1.1 s
- Jagged array, manual loops, serial: 2.4 s
- Jagged array, manual loops, PLINQ: 0.8 s

Comment: I'm pretty stuck with the multidimensional arrays for the moment, but your other approaches give me some ideas, thank you!

Comment: How fast is that `Enqueue()` function, do you think? If it had a place inside the innermost loop and stored 4-tuples of `(i,j,k,value)` then I would have a way to do some sparse array work that I need elsewhere.

Comment: @RobPerkins If it's a sparse array, then I think it should be fast enough. But you'll have to measure that for yourself.

Comment: svick, so far the timings are very good for my particular data set. The `OrderablePartitioner` is creating a partition for only two items in the array per partition, though, which is not something I expected. Unless that's normal with two 6-core hyperthreaded CPUs?

Comment: @RobPerkins You mean the `Paritioner.Create()`? That depends on how large your first dimension is. On my quad-core, it seems to always create something around 10-15 partitions. But if you don't like that, you can use [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992635) that lets you specify exactly what the size of partitions should be.

Comment: I saw that; I guess 24 threads/12 cores really means something!